# in pug do an iteration and give it a limit

Tags: json, for-loop, pug, limit

I want to limit a function (for)

to recycle the same database from a json file

```
- for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; ++i) {
  a.contenido_a(href="/pelicula/"+datos[i].titulo)
   img.card-img-top(src=datos[i].imagen, alt=alt=datos[i].titulo)
- };
```

the typical function but I modify it to obtain to give it the limit

```
- for( var i = 0; i < datos.length >= 5; ++i) {
  a.contenido_a(href="/pelicula/"+datos[i].titulo)
   img.card-img-top(src=datos[i].imagen, alt=alt=datos[i].titulo)
- };
```

if I define it like this there is no error but nothing appears on the screen, but if I define it like this if there is an error

```
- for (var i = 0; i < datos.length <= 5; ++i) {
  a.contenido_a(href="/pelicula/"+datos[i].titulo)
   img.card-img-top(src=datos[i].imagen, alt=alt=datos[i].titulo)
- };
```

Comment: digamos una base de datos de 20 elementos solo sacar los 5 primeros

Comment: Translation of the above comment: "Let's say for a database of 20 elements, only get the first 5".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the first set of elements from a database, but limit the number to 5 if there are more than 5, you could write it like this:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < datos.length && i < 5; ++i)
  a.contenido_a(href='/pelicula/' + datos[i].titulo)
    img.card-img-top(src=datos[i].imagen, alt=datos[i].titulo)
```

The expression `i < datos.length && i < 5` is only true if `i` is less than the length of `datos` and `i` is less than 5.

Also note that the `{`, and `}` aren't required for `for` loops in the latest version of Pug.